# Как узнать значение каждого input в форме не зная ни type ни name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

я пытался так:

```
form.find('input').filter(function () {
    this.val();
});
```

но выдает ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#form').find('input').each(function(i, v) {
  console.log($(v).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="form">
  <input type="text" value="1" />
  <input type="text" value="2" />
</form>
```